# Info about network adapters

Tags: networking, adapter

If possible, can I get some informations about how to find out my network adapters and some more stuff about them, such as MAC addresses, their manufacturers, how can I find out which network adapter has an active connection and how many IP addresses do they have, ***in cmd!***

Thanks!

Comment: currently working on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

For the basics through ipconfig https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ipconfig.mspx?mfr=true

For more advanced stuff you can use the Windows Networking Shell https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx

To map a MAC address to the manufacturers' OUI you may need to use a 3rd party tool https://aruljohn.com/mac.pl

Answer (score 1):

Win+R and type cmd. Then type the command **ipconfig -all**.[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmrJf.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig /all` lists everything you could possibly want to know about your network adapters.

Alternatively, using Powershell:

```
gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description, ipenabled, ipaddress, macaddress | fl; gwmi win32_networkadapter | select name, Manufacturer
```